# alternative to `tail -f <filename>` allowing printing continuous stream from multiple files in multiple folders under the same parent folder

Tags: rhel, tail

As far as I know, `tail -f <filename>` allows to continuously print newly appended data from one single file.

What if I need to get content **from multiple files** located in multiple folders under the same parent folder, then filter that content if need be, and finally print it as a real-time stream, as new data gets appended to any one of the multiple monitored files?

EDIT: the operating system is RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.4

Comment: Did you search for `multitail`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas RedHat 7.4

Comment: Are new files or directories being created/removed there while you're `tail`ing that folder? If yes, should they be dynamically added to the list of files to monitor? May there be hard links or symlinks?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes indeed new folders with new files are dynamically added, and these new ones are to be monitored too. Please take a look at my own answer below and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following oneliner:

`while true; do cat /path/to/numerous/folders/and/files/*/*.txt | grep "some filter" | tail -n 10; sleep 1; done`

Every 1 second, the script will print 10 last lines of the filtered stream.

To break the loop, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Is this really what you wanted? Unlike `tail -f`, it will repeat the same lines over and over if there is no change, and can miss lines if more than 10 lines are added to a file in the 1-second window.

Comment: @n.st This oneliner did the job pretty well so far. At least for the time being.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
ls /path/to/files/to/be/monitored/by/tail | while read fname; do tail -f $fname & done; wait
```

Comment: There was a typo: `ls /path/to/files/to/be/monitored/by/tail | while read fname; do tail -f $fname &; done`

Comment: Please [edit your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/485907/edit) to fix the typo. You don't need to comment on it.